# How can i check if a user already exist in firebase using nest.js code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nestjs

I'm trying to check if the email of the registered user is already found in firebase or not, before creating a new user in the firebase.
Here is where I create a user:

```
async create(user: UserRegisterDto) {
  let newUser = this.saveUserModel(user);
  return await this.firebaseService
    .createFirebaseUser(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then(res => {
      const firebaseUser = JSON.parse(res);
      (newUser).id = firebaseUser.uid;
      return this.saveUserRecord(newUser);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
}
```

and this is the UserRegisterDto object:

```
export class UserRegisterDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  fullName: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `firebaseService`? Like `createUser()` method should throw and error if user already exists.

Comment: Can you update your question with code of `createFirebaseUser`? You can add a catch to `createuser({ email, password }).then((e) => /**/)` there and check if error is user already exists

Comment: @Dharmaraj To be honest, I don't know if that is possible for sure. I need to handle those errors like: auth/email-already-exists, auth/user-not-found and so on..

Comment: Like `createUser()` would throw errors like `auth/email-already-exists` and not `user not found`... but you can use [`getUserByEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth#baseauthgetuserbyemail) before that to check if user exists then ..

Comment: This is how I looks from the inside @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if a user already exists in Firebase Authentication for a specific email address, you can call the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). If the array it returns is empty, the email isn't used by any user yet.